# Создание telegram bot на python

Tags: python, telebot

Есть функции, посредством которых прошу пользователя ввести определенные данные. 
Но если пользователь зашел в этот блок, а потом передумал заполнять данные и решил перейти в другие разделы бота, бот начинает отправлять ему сообщения из прошлого блока, что он ввел что-то некорректно.

Как выходить из функций при переходе между блоками.

Пример кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp="Payeer")
def payeer(message):
    state = dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)
    if state == config.States.S_ENTER_PAYEER.value:
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
       """В прошлый раз вы не законьчили 
       ввод ваших Payeer реквизитов.""")
   else: # Под "остальным" понимаем состояние "0" - начало диалога
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
       """Введите № вашего кошелька 
       Payeer: """)
   dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.S_ENTER_PAYEER.value)
```

Comment: Присылайте ему кнопочку типа "вернуться в главное меню"

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю ответ на этот вопрос такой же, как и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782537/telebot-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-regexp/783064#783064)

`bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, main_body)`, main_body - название метода к которому будет совершён переход.

Пример смотреть [здесь](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
Hi there, I am Example bot.
What's your name?
""")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)


def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text
        user = User(name)
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'How old are you?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
    except Exception as e:
bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')
```

Comment: Добавте содержимое из ссылок в ответ (возможно сокращённо), чтобы он остался содержательным ответом даже после того, как ссылки помрут.

Comment: @0xdb , часть кода из ссылки добавил.