# telebot. Обработка сообщения после сообщения по regexp

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть обычный хэндлер, где сообщение должно соответствовать определенному regexp. Как сделать так, чтобы следующе сообщение обрабатывалось другим определенным хэндлером, а не написанными после первого (общими)?
Грубо говоря, хочу создать цепочку вопросов, вопросы которой зависят от предыдущих ответов.
Один способ - создать инлайновые кнопки (callback) и по нажатию изменять их контент, но интересуют именно вводимые пользователем бота сообщения.
Можно ли это создать с помощью стандартных средств telebot или можно только через кэширование действий пользователя?

Comment: Сообщения бот получает. Вы их как-то можете обработать, в чем вопрос-то? :)

Comment: @gil9red , он использует библиотеку [telebot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Comment: @gil9red, в telebot метод обработки сообщения оборачивается в хэндлер-декоратор, который ловит по определенному шаблону. Хендлеров несколько. Когда бот получает сообщение, то перебирает хендлеры, пока не попадется первый соответствующий шаблон (на нем перебор и заканчивается и выдается ответ бота).

Comment: Проще говоря, мне нужно как-то сохранить предыдущий ответ пользователя не прибегая к таким затратным средствам как бд. В api telebot, я не нашел такой возможности (инлайн кнопки с колбеком не считаются). Только обработка одного сообщения.

Comment: Храните в памяти. Создайте список и в него храните сообщения пользователей. Вот только список нужно будет после куда-то сохранять (база данных), либо он при каждом запуске бота будет заново создаваться. Да и память может в итоге закончиться. При запуске бота создайте список: `messages = []` и при получении сообщения в него добавляйте сообщения. А дальше уже сами думайте и решайте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, main_body)`, main_body - название метода к которому будет совершён переход

Вот [тут](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) есть отличный пример.

Comment: Огромное вам стаковерфловоское спасибо! Это именно то, что я искал!

Comment: Пожалуйста, кстати, рекомендую этот репозиторий создателей телебота, там можно найти 90% ответов на простые вопросы в ботострении.